# Does there exists a homeomorphisms which are not isometries,but preserves completeness??

Tags: general-topology, continuity, metric-spaces, isometry, complete-spaces

> Does there exists a homeomorphisms which are not isometries,but
> preserves completeness??

The above question clicked my mind while studying the relations

$1)$Isometry$\implies$ Homeomorphism$\implies$ Continuity

$2)$ Isometry preserves Completeness.

I searched lot in books but do  not get any result...Please give some suggestions

Comment: Think about the proof that isometries preserve completeness. Is there a slightly weaker condition on the map that would make the same proof go through?

Comment: @JamieRadcliffe:Let $X$ and $Y$ be metric spaces with metrics (e.g., distances) $d_X$ and $d_Y$. A map $f : X → Y$ is called an isometry or distance preserving if for any $a,b ∈ X$ one has

${\displaystyle d_{Y}\!\left(f(a),f(b)\right)=d_{X}(a,b)}$ 

for getting the desired result the equality in the last equation should be loosened i.e. it should become ${\displaystyle d_{Y}\!\left(f(a),f(b)\right)\le d_{X}(a,b)}$

Comment: @JamieRadcliffe:Consider $f:\mathbb R\rightarrow \mathbb R$ [a homeomorphism](both domain and codomain equipped with usual metric) defined as $f(x)=x^3$ .Consider a Cauchy sequence $<1/n>$ in codomain then consider $\vert \frac{1}{n^3}-\frac{1}{m^3}\vert=\vert \frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{m}\vert.\vert \frac{1}{n^2}+\frac{1}{m^2}+\frac{1}{nm}\vert\le\vert \frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{m}\vert\le\epsilon$

Comment: @JamieRadcliffe:Please review my approach

Comment: You example is an interesting one, but not very fleshed out. Your example of a sequence in the codomain--is it intended to show that completeness is preserved or that it is not?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question, but taking $\mathbb{R}$ with euclidean metric and $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ with $f(x) = 2x$, then $f$ is a homeomorphism and is not an isometry and it's clear that it preserves completeness. Wasn't that something you were looking for?